# SQL Server 2008, Normalization, and Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that I have been searching for a while on but have been unable to sufficiently answer.

I am inserting records into my 2008 SQL Server for my SQL class and I had to normalize the data into the third form. I believe I did this correctly and the example given to me was to separate records into their own atomic rows (among the other requirements). This produced several rows with the same OrderID (which is my primary key) and split the parts of the order up into said rows.

Example:

```
OrderID ItemNumber Price  QTY
101     1          $1.00  5
101     2          $9.00  4
101     3          $5.00  3
```

However how can I insert these rows with my PK (OrderID) duplicating itself so many times? I have tried once already and it rejects every INSERT INTO other than the first instance that isn't duplicated (gives me a PK constraint error). I apologize if this is a stupid question but I am trying hard to understand. The little example I posted above is EXACTLY how my instructor wanted it as well.

Comment: Your primary key on this table is not the OrderID, it's a composite key of OrderID and ItemNumber.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, it should be a composite key. Maybe I did something incorrect when I was generating my schema? (we had to use Erwin to forward engineer our schema). I will look now.

Answer (score 0):

So as you may or may not have learned in class, one of the constraints of a primary key is that it must be unique.

From a more logical perspective, the primary key should in essence define what each row represents to a business user. In this case, each row represents an item, not an order. Each item is defined by the order number, and the item number of that order.

Your primary key should be a composite of OrderID and ItemNumber.

Comment: Just an aside, and don't want to distract from the question nor start a natural-vs-artificial-key flamewar, but in real life I would recommend not using OrderID and ItemNumber as a primary key; what if you need to add the same item to the order at a different price..something like OrderID and LineNumber are a better choice of PK

Comment: Actually this makes sense to me. Much more sense than how it was explained to me. In my homework he is asking us, however, to make a composite key of OrderID and CustomerID. How could this ever be unique in multiple instances though (if this makes sense)?

Comment: Stephen Byrne would you want the price of a product you ordered to change after placing the order? You might be correct when talking about the actual products, but this is an order table.

Comment: @JodyT no not at all, but in a real situation you may want to put 10 of Item A at 19.99 and 1 free at 0.00...in the OrderID/ItemNumber key situation, you can't; you're stuck with a workaround that stores 11 of Item A at 18.19 which just looks wrong  :)

Comment: @user2132765, the only way this makes sense as explained would be in a typical order schema design where you have both an OrderHeader (which of course can and probably should be unique by OrderID/CustomerID) and OrderLines related table -- related by OrderID which is a Foreign key from OrderHeader -- which cannot have a unique OrderID/CustomerID unless you only have a single line and cannot have a unique OrderID/ItemNumber unless you never repeat items on the same order, which is not really practical.
I hope that makes sense?